# JSON to PHP API not happening

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to save data on click of button using Javascript and PHP.

Button click:

```
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "savedata.php";
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            /*xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(json.rawText + ", " + json.convertedText);
                }
            };*/
            var data = JSON.stringify({"rawText": rt, "convertedText": ct});
            xhr.send(data);
```

savedata.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

require('db/db.php');
session_start();

    $saverawText = $_POST['rawText'];
    $saveConvertedText = $_POST['convertedText'];

    $ins_query="insert into cmn_data (`rawtext`,`convertedtext`) values ('$saverawText','$saveConvertedText')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $ins_query);

?>
```

In Db: One record is created but it is empty so every time I click save button 1 record is created but empty. What is the wrong the above syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message or behavior you are seeing?  What's in the console?  What's in the error log?

Comment: First https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1, also remove `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: No error message.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : I removed it but does it make a difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest  Check this out and see if it helps you understand how to send params via AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not parse JSON requests to $_POST array itself. You should either parse request body in php:

```php
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$saverawText = $request['rawText'];
$saveConvertedText = $request['convertedText'];
```

or pass data to request with FormaData object:

```js
var data = new FormData();
data.append("rawText", rt);
data.append("convertedText", ct);
xhr.send(data);
```

And as mentioned before, including user input directly into sql could cause sql injections. Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to escape user inputs or PDO driver, which is bit more complicated but more reliable approach.

Comment: forgot to wrap `php://input` with `file_get_contents` and parse json as associative array. updated `$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`
Try it, should work now

Answer (score 0):

You can POST your values like that :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "savedata.php";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
/*xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json.rawText + ", " + json.convertedText);
    }
};*/
var data = "rawText=" + rt + "&convertedText=" + ct;
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: I can't send the data via JSON?